# How to connect plunker to a local Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors, plunker

I want to connect my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/1k2SAZ?p=info) to a node server running on my local machine. I want to achieve this in order to obtain some data from a database. At the moment I have created some sample data in the `app.js` file on my plunk.

Is there any way to do this? If not with plunker, is there any alternative where I can run Node.js apps online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question about an alternative for hosting Node.js apps you could have a look at [Cloud9](https://c9.io/)

Update:
It is possible to connect to a local machine but you have to take [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) into consideration. I made a quick sample to show you that it is possible. Following is a simple Node.js application which responds with "Huhu!" when sending a `GET` to http://localhost:3000/ping

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('express-cors')
var app = express();

app.use(cors({
    allowedOrigins: [
        'run.plnkr.co'
    ]
}));

app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Huhu!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

In addition, [here is a simple Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXlMMBPzNlxZRhxyafSW) for connecting to it, whereby the 'important' part is

```
$scope.pingLocalNodeServer = function() {
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/ping')
       .then(function(response) {
          $scope.echo = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
          $scope.err = error;
        });
  };
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: So there is no way I can connect plunker to a server?

Comment: That helped me! I was able to connect to `localhost` and get required data perfectly. But suddenly after a break started getting an exception like this:

`Exception { message: "", result: 2153644038, name: "", filename: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/l…", lineNumber: 9866, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: "createHttpBackend/<@https://cdnjs.c…" }` . I am using firefox. 
Refer my plunk : https://plnkr.co/edit/1k2SAZ?p=preview

Comment: I realized that it was the secure connection (https) that was creating some problem for cross domain connection. After reloading the page with `http` instead of `https` everything seems to work fine!!